# Find with regular expression MongoDB + PHP

Tags: php, regex, mongodb, php-mongodb

I'm trying to do a PHP `find` over a MongoDB collection using [MongoRegex](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongoregex.php), but I'm not able to make it work. The code is quite easy:

```
$cursor = $this->collection->find($params)
//$params has this value:
//Array
//(
//    [name] => MongoRegex Object
//    (
//       [regex] => .*victor.*
//       [flags] => i
//    )
//    [login] => MongoRegex Object
//    (
//        [regex] => .*victor.*
//        [flags] => i
//    )
//)
```

This `$params` array is constructed with this function:

```
function toRegEx($entryVars=array()){
    $regexVars = array();
    foreach($entryVars as $var => $value){
        $regexVal = html_entity_decode($value);
        $regexVars[$var] = new MongoRegex("/.*".$regexVal.".*/i");
    }
    return $regexVars;
}
```

For some reason, this query is only returning the values which makes an exact match (i.e. the documents where login or name are exactly "victor"). What I want is that the query returns all the documents where login and/or name **contains** the word "victor". I'm pretty sure I'm missing something basic, but I'm not being able to find it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose you simply anchored the regexp to the beginning of the subject string (**^**), try without :

```
$regexVars[$var] = new MongoRegex("/".$regexVal."/i");
```

---

**EDIT**:
Also, if the print_r dump of the $params array above is accurate, you're probably missing a **$or** statement somewhere to reflect your conditions. By default, the mongodb query criteria are linked with a "and" logic, so your query will return records matching regexps on both fields only.